# Mouseover to find button - cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, mouseevent

I have got a calendar then when i move the mouse a bit down from a date I need to get a button, that is the button will appear upon hovering..

I have this code:

```js
const myDate = dayjs().subtract(5, 'day')
cy.get('.calendar-row')
  .contains(myDate.format('DD / MM'))
  .trigger('mouseout')
  .trigger('mousemove', 50, 50)
  .within(() => {
    cy.get('.mybutton').should('be.visible')
   })
 })
})
```

The test is failing with the following error:

> Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.trigger() failed because this element:
> `<div class="calendar-row">08 / 07</div>`
> is being covered by another element:
> `<button type="button" class="mybutton" title="mybutton">...</button>`
> Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking

The error happens at the step: `trigger mousemove, 50, 50`

When the mouse move down i need it to find the button "mybutton" for this specific date.
Can someone pls advise what i am doing wrong.
thanks

Comment: There is insufficient detail, please advise which calendar - is it React, Angular, etc?

Comment: It is a react calendar. Whatever i do the mouseevent wont work..

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `mouseout`, it already causes the hover button to appear.

```js
const myDate = dayjs().subtract(5, 'day')
cy.get('.calendar-row')
  .contains(myDate.format('DD / MM'))
  //.trigger('mouseout')                   // comment this out
  .trigger('mousemove', 50, 50)            // OR this one
cy.get('.mybutton').should('be.visible')
```

The message is telling you that `<button type="button" class="mybutton" title="mybutton">...</button>` has appeared already, so it is the 2nd `.trigger()` that throws the error.

You would only need one or other mouse action - I would try commenting out one then the other and see which gives the result.

Comment: I have tried the above it is saying:
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: mybutton but never found it.

Comment: What calendar are you using?

Comment: BTW - see note in the code, you can try the opposite -  keep `mouseout` and remove `movemove`

Comment: i have tried the below:
cy.get('.calendar-row')
  .contains(myDate.format('DD / MM'))
  .trigger("mousedown", 50, 70, {force:true}).trigger('mouseenter')

From mousedown it moves down a bit and then whatever i want to trigger next it triggers it on calendar-row so it never finds the button..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `force: true` to trigger.

```js
const myDate = dayjs().subtract(5, 'day')
cy.get('.calendar-row')
  .contains(myDate.format('DD / MM'))
  .trigger('mouseout', {force: true})
  .trigger('mousemove', 50, 50, {force: true})
cy.get('.mybutton').should('be.visible')
```

Comment: I tried your solution too i got Expected to find element: mybutton but never found it.

Answer (score 0):

At the end this worked:

```
const myDate = dayjs().subtract(5, 'day')
cy.get('.calendar-row').contains(myDate.format('DD / MM')).parent().trigger('mouseout',50, 50).trigger('mousemove').within(() => {

  cy.get('.mybutton').should('be.visible')
})
})
```

Thanks